# Manipulating X11 window menu in a WM-agnostic way

Tags: qt, gtk, x11, xlib, ewmh

Motif-based window managers ([`Mwm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_Window_Manager), [`Dtwm`](http://cdesktopenv.sourceforge.net/man1/dtwm.html), [`4Dwm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4Dwm), [`5Dwm`](http://5dwm.org/maxxi/screenshots.html)) allow custom menu items (with the corresponding callbacks) to be added to the application's window menu (see the screenshot, gist available [here](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/6d19825780d814ac788c)). The application itself is also required to link with `-lXm` (at least for `XmAddProtocols()` and `XmAddProtocolCallback()` to be available).

[image: Mwm custom window menu]

From the *X Window* perspective, this is achieved via a couple of extra `Atom`s set by the client:

```
_MOTIF_WM_MESSAGES(ATOM) = _MOTIF_WM_OFFSET, CUSTOM_MENU_ACTION_A, CUSTOM_MENU_ACTION_B
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, _MOTIF_WM_MESSAGES
_MOTIF_WM_MENU(STRING) = "no-label                                 f.separator\n
    Custom\ Menu\ Title                      f.title\n
    XTerm                                    f.exec \"xterm &\"\n
    Custom\ Menu\ Action\ A Shift Alt<Key>F1 f.send_msg 393\n
    Custom\ Menu\ Action\ B Shift Alt<Key>F2 f.send_msg 394\n"
```

Apparently, this behavior is not supported by any of the modern *EWMH*-compliant window managers. Additionally, [EWMH specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/) doesn't seem to provide any alternative.

Is there any non-Motif cross-WM way to manipulate the window menu (*GTK*, *Qt* or *Xlib*)?

Comment: Not even non-cross-WM ways. Only Motif has this.